# Failed ping healthcheck after deploying TF2.1 model with TF-serving-container on AWS Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-serving, amazon-sagemaker

We want to deploy a trained Tensorflow Model to AWS Sagemaker for inference with a tensorflow-serving-container. Tensorflow version is 2.1. Following the guide at https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-tensorflow-serving-container the following steps have been taken:

1. Build TF 2.1 AMI and publish it to AWS ECR after sucessful local testing
2. Setting Sagemaker Execution Role Permissions for S3 and ECR.
3. Pack saved TF model folder (saved_model.pb, assets, variables) into model.tar.gz
4. Created endpoint with realtime predictor:

```
import os
import sagemaker
from sagemaker.tensorflow.serving import Model
from sagemaker.tensorflow.model import TensorFlowModel
from sagemaker.predictor import json_deserializer, json_serializer, RealTimePredictor
from sagemaker.content_types import CONTENT_TYPE_JSON

def create_tfs_sagemaker_model():
    sagemaker_session = sagemaker.Session()
    role = 'arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:role/service-role/AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole-XXXXXXX
    bucket = 'tf-serving'
    prefix = 'sagemaker/tfs-test'
    s3_path = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, prefix)
    image = 'XXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/sagemaker-tensorflow-serving:2.1.0-cpu'
    model_data = sagemaker_session.upload_data('model.tar.gz', bucket, os.path.join(prefix, 'model'))
    endpoint_name = 'tf-serving-ep-test-1'
    tensorflow_serving_model = Model(model_data=model_data, role=role, sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session, image=image, framework_version='2.1')
    tensorflow_serving_model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.c4.xlarge', endpoint_name=endpoint_name)
    rt_predictor = RealTimePredictor(endpoint=endpoint_name, sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session, serializer=json_serializer, content_type=CONTENT_TYPE_JSON, accept=CONTENT_TYPE_JSON)
```

5. Create batch-transform job:

```
def create_tfs_sagemaker_batch_transform():
    sagemaker_session = sagemaker.Session()
    print(sagemaker_session.boto_region_name)
    role = 'arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXX:role/service-role/AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole-XXXXXXXX'
    bucket = 'XXXXXXX-tf-serving'
    prefix = 'sagemaker/tfs-test'
    image = 'XXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/sagemaker-tensorflow-serving:2.1.0-cpu'
    s3_path = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, prefix)
    model_data = sagemaker_session.upload_data('model.tar.gz', bucket, os.path.join(prefix, 'model'))
    tensorflow_serving_model = Model(model_data=model_data, role=role, sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session, image=image, name='deep-net-0', framework_version='2.1')
    print(tensorflow_serving_model.model_data)
    out_path = 's3://XXXXXX-serving-out/'
    input_path = "s3://XXXXXX-serving-in/"    
    tensorflow_serving_transformer = tensorflow_serving_model.transformer(instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.c4.xlarge', accept='application/json', output_path=out_path)
    tensorflow_serving_transformer.transform(input_path, content_type='application/json')
```

Both steps 4 and 5 are running and in the AWS Cloudwatch logs we see successful starting of the instances, loading of the model and TF-Serving entering the event loop – see below:

> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.156+02:00 INFO:**main**:starting services
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.156+02:00 INFO:**main**:nginx config:
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.156+02:00 load_module
> modules/ngx_http_js_module.so;
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.156+02:00 worker_processes auto;
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.156+02:00 daemon off;
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.156+02:00 pid /tmp/nginx.pid;
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.157+02:00 error_log /dev/stderr error;
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.157+02:00 worker_rlimit_nofile 4096;
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.157+02:00 events { worker_connections 2048;
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.157+02:00 }
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.162+02:00 http { include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
> default_type application/json; access_log /dev/stdout combined;
> js_include tensorflow-serving.js; upstream tfs_upstream { server
> localhost:10001; } upstream gunicorn_upstream { server
> unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=1; } server { listen 8080
> deferred; client_max_body_size 0; client_body_buffer_size 100m;
> subrequest_output_buffer_size 100m; set $tfs_version 2.1; set
> $default_tfs_model None; location /tfs { rewrite ^/tfs/(.*) /$1 break;
> proxy_redirect off; proxy_pass_request_headers off; proxy_set_header
> Content-Type 'application/json'; proxy_set_header Accept
> 'application/json'; proxy_pass http://tfs_upstream; } location /ping {
> js_content ping; } location /invocations { js_content invocations; }
> location /models { proxy_pass http://gunicorn_upstream/models; }
> location / { return 404 '{"error": "Not Found"}'; } keepalive_timeout
> 3; }
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.162+02:00 }
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.162+02:00 INFO:tfs_utils:using default model name:
> model
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.162+02:00 INFO:tfs_utils:tensorflow serving model
> config:
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.162+02:00 model_config_list: { config: { name:
> "model", base_path: "/opt/ml/model", model_platform: "tensorflow" }
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.162+02:00 }
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.162+02:00 INFO:**main**:using default model name:
> model
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.162+02:00 INFO:**main**:tensorflow serving model
> config:
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.163+02:00 model_config_list: { config: { name:
> "model", base_path: "/opt/ml/model", model_platform: "tensorflow" }
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.163+02:00 }
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.163+02:00 INFO:**main**:tensorflow version info:
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.163+02:00 TensorFlow ModelServer:
> 2.1.0-rc1+dev.sha.075ffcf
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.163+02:00 TensorFlow Library: 2.1.0
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.163+02:00 INFO:**main**:tensorflow serving
> command: tensorflow_model_server --port=10000 --rest_api_port=10001
> --model_config_file=/sagemaker/model-config.cfg --max_num_load_retries=0
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.163+02:00 INFO:**main**:started tensorflow serving
> (pid: 13)
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.163+02:00 INFO:**main**:nginx version info:
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.163+02:00 nginx version: nginx/1.18.0
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.163+02:00 built by gcc 7.4.0 (Ubuntu
> 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.163+02:00 built with OpenSSL 1.1.1 11 Sep 2018
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.163+02:00 TLS SNI support enabled
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.163+02:00 configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx
> --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-compat --with-file-aio --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_v2_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream --with-stream_realip_module --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/data/builder/debuild/nginx-1.18.0/debian/debuild-base/nginx-1.18.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -pie'
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.163+02:00 INFO:**main**:started nginx (pid: 15)
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.163+02:00 2020-07-08 15:07:15.075708: I
> tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:462] Adding/updating
> models.
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.163+02:00 2020-07-08 15:07:15.075760: I
> tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:573] (Re-)adding
> model: model
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.163+02:00 2020-07-08 15:07:15.180755: I
> tensorflow_serving/util/retrier.cc:46] Retrying of Reserving resources
> for servable: {name: model version: 1} exhausted max_num_retries: 0
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.163+02:00 2020-07-08 15:07:15.180887: I
> tensorflow_serving/core/basic_manager.cc:739] Successfully reserved
> resources to load servable {name: model version: 1}
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.163+02:00 2020-07-08 15:07:15.180919: I
> tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:66] Approving load for
> servable version {name: model version: 1}
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.163+02:00 2020-07-08 15:07:15.180944: I
> tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:74] Loading servable version
> {name: model version: 1}
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.163+02:00 2020-07-08 15:07:15.180995: I
> external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:31]
> Reading SavedModel from: /opt/ml/model/1
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.163+02:00 2020-07-08 15:07:15.205712: I
> external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:54]
> Reading meta graph with tags { serve }
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.164+02:00 2020-07-08 15:07:15.205825: I
> external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:264]
> Reading SavedModel debug info (if present) from: /opt/ml/model/1
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.164+02:00 2020-07-08 15:07:15.208599: I
> external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:147]
> Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 2. Tune using
> inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance.
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:16.164+02:00 2020-07-08 15:07:15.328057: I
> external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:203]
> Restoring SavedModel bundle.
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:17.165+02:00 2020-07-08 15:07:16.578796: I
> external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:152]
> Running initialization op on SavedModel bundle at path:
> /opt/ml/model/1
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:17.165+02:00 2020-07-08 15:07:16.626494: I
> external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:333]
> SavedModel load for tags { serve }; Status: success: OK. Took 1445495
> microseconds.
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:17.165+02:00 2020-07-08 15:07:16.630443: I
> tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/saved_model_warmup.cc:105] No
> warmup data file found at
> /opt/ml/model/1/assets.extra/tf_serving_warmup_requests
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:17.165+02:00 2020-07-08 15:07:16.632461: I
> tensorflow_serving/util/retrier.cc:46] Retrying of Loading servable:
> {name: model version: 1} exhausted max_num_retries: 0
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:17.165+02:00 2020-07-08 15:07:16.632484: I
> tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:87] Successfully loaded
> servable version {name: model version: 1}
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:17.165+02:00 2020-07-08 15:07:16.634727: I
> tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:362] Running gRPC
> ModelServer at 0.0.0.0:10000 ...
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:17.165+02:00 [warn] getaddrinfo: address family for
> nodename not supported
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:17.165+02:00 2020-07-08 15:07:16.635747: I
> tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:382] Exporting HTTP/REST
> API at:localhost:10001 ...
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:17.165+02:00 [evhttp_server.cc : 238] NET_LOG:
> Entering the event loop …

But both (endpoint and batch transform) fail the Sagemaker Ping Health check with:

> 2020-07-08T17:07:32.169+02:00 2020/07/08 15:07:31 [error] 16#16: *1
> js: failed ping{ "error": "Could not find any versions of model None"
> }
>
> 2020-07-08T17:07:32.170+02:00
> 169.254.255.130 - - [08/Jul/2020:15:07:31 +0000] "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"

Also, when tested locally with self built docker tf-serving-container the model is running without problems and can be queried with curl.
What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though your model is named `"model"` to TensorFlow Serving earlier in the logs:

```
2020-07-08T17:07:16.162+02:00 INFO:main:using default model name: model
2020-07-08T17:07:16.162+02:00 INFO:main:tensorflow serving model config:
```

but in the error, the ping check is getting routed to TensorFlow Serving as a model named: `"None"

```
`Could not find any versions of model None`
```

I'm not sure if this error is happening due to the Docker container or on the SageMaker side. But... I did find this suspicious environment variable `TFS_DEFAULT_MODEL_NAME` that is set to `"None"` by default:

```
class PythonServiceResource:

    def __init__(self):
        if SAGEMAKER_MULTI_MODEL_ENABLED:
            self._model_tfs_rest_port = {}
            self._model_tfs_grpc_port = {}
            self._model_tfs_pid = {}
            self._tfs_ports = self._parse_sagemaker_port_range(SAGEMAKER_TFS_PORT_RANGE)
        else:
            self._tfs_grpc_port = TFS_GRPC_PORT
            self._tfs_rest_port = TFS_REST_PORT

        self._tfs_enable_batching = SAGEMAKER_BATCHING_ENABLED == 'true'
        self._tfs_default_model_name = os.environ.get('TFS_DEFAULT_MODEL_NAME', "None")
```

Could you try setting `TFS_DEFAULT_MODEL_NAME` in your container and see what happens?

If that doesn't work, you might have some more success posting a bug on the [TensorFlow SageMaker container github](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-tensorflow-serving-container/issues). Amazon experts check that fairly regularly.

BTW, I'd love to chat more about how you're using SageMaker endpoints with TensorFlow models for some research I'm doing. If you're up for it, shoot me an email at `yoavz@modelzoo.dev`.

Comment: This could be right. But during the local build of a non-AWS TFS container, I bind a local  model on disk to the server, which takes care of correct binding. This makes for easy model exchange during testing. For production the final model would be integrated into the container itself. I expect the same behaviour for AWS-TFS where the Sagemaker Image binds the model in S3 to the container. I have also tried setting the modelname, but without success. So somewhere in the process the model name gets lost? I will test it with a standard example from aws-github, to check if that works.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem is as follows:

Environmentvariable "SAGEMAKER_TFS_DEFAULT_MODEL_NAME" needs to be set to correct model name e.g. "model"

```
import os
import sagemaker
from sagemaker.tensorflow.serving import Model
from sagemaker.tensorflow.model import TensorFlowModel
from sagemaker.predictor import json_deserializer, json_serializer, RealTimePredictor
from sagemaker.content_types import CONTENT_TYPE_JSON

def create_tfs_sagemaker_model():
    sagemaker_session = sagemaker.Session()
    role = 'arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:role/service-role/AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole-XXXXXXX
    bucket = 'tf-serving'
    prefix = 'sagemaker/tfs-test'
    s3_path = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, prefix)
    image = 'XXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/sagemaker-tensorflow-serving:2.1.0-cpu'
    model_data = sagemaker_session.upload_data('model.tar.gz', bucket, os.path.join(prefix, 'model'))
    endpoint_name = 'tf-serving-ep-test-1'
    env = {"SAGEMAKER_TFS_DEFAULT_MODEL_NAME": "model"}
    tensorflow_serving_model = Model(model_data=model_data, role=role, sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session, image=image, name='model', framework_version='2.1', env=env)
    tensorflow_serving_model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.c4.xlarge', endpoint_name=endpoint_name)
    rt_predictor = RealTimePredictor(endpoint=endpoint_name, sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session, serializer=json_serializer, content_type=CONTENT_TYPE_JSON, accept=CONTENT_TYPE_JSON)
```

This creates the endpoint correctly and passes the ping health check with:

2020-07-16T12:08:20.654+02:00
10.32.0.2 - - [16/Jul/2020:10:08:20 +0000] "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "AHC/2.0"